# Temp Table with Wild Card

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, wildcard, temp-tables

I need to clean up some observations in a table that are inaccurate prior to joining to the after mentioned table, this will avoid duplicate observation output.

I validated that the max(date_value) removes the 9K inaccurate transactions ..... newer transaction were completed which fixed the problem.

The code below, without into #temp, fixes the issue but as soon as I add a temp table, I get a  syntax error will not execute, I need like 20 variables out of the table and really don't feel like listing them all, must be a simple syntax or alternative method.

```
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM db.dbo.table WHERE MAX(date_value);
```

Comment: `WHERE MAX(date_value) = ?` WHERE clauses need an expression. But it's not really clear what you are trying to do here. Maybe a CTE with a row number to identify the max date_value? Then filter on row number. There are many examples of this out on the intertubes.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT a.* INTO #temp 
FROM table a
inner join (select id, max(created_at) as max_created
 from db.table
 group by id) b
    on a.id = b.id

Comment: feel pretty silly that I posted been doing to much r and python recently